# Assigning values of an array in a loop

Tags: arrays, loops, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

In my code:

```
DO i=1,numJog,1
    IF(val(i) .EQV. .TRUE.)THEN
            DO j=1,contVenc,1
                result(j) = i
            END DO
    END IF
END DO
```

Where `val` is a logical array, and `result` is a integer array.

For example, if `val` is:

```
F
T
F
T
```

Then, `i=2` and `i=4`.

But the `result` array just write 4 twice. For example:

```
DO i=1,contVenc,1
    WRITE(*,*) result(i)
END DO
```

The result is:

```
4
4
```

Instead of

```
2
4
```

If I make some changes in my code like:

```
DO i=1,numJog,1
    IF(val(i) .EQV. .TRUE.)THEN
        WRITE(*,*) i
    END IF
END DO
```

The result is:

```
2
4
```

As I wanted.

Conclusion, I think this second loop is causing this problem.

Comment: `(val(i) .EQV. .TRUE.)` can just be `val(i)`, but that is just style. Also, appending the `,1` to each loop is uncommon and looks weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your second loop is at fault here.  You haven't said what `contVenc` is, but it crucially doesn't change at any point in the fragment you have there.  That just means that the same elements of `result` are being assigned to whenever you have a `.TRUE.` in `val`.

In your case they are both set to `2` for the first `.TRUE.` and are then both set to `4` for the second.

You are more likely to mean something like (with extra tidying):

```
j = 0
DO i=1,numJog
    IF (val(i)) THEN
        j = j+1   ! Test this as a bound
        result(j) = i
    END IF
END DO
```

But then, I'd just use `PACK`.  Your intended loop has the same effect as

```
result(1:COUNT(val(1:numJog))) = PACK([(i,i=1,numJog)], val(1:numJog))
```

Again hoping that `result` is large enough.

That said, if `numJog` is just the size of the array `val` (that is, you aren't just doing this on a sub-array) then, as High Performance Mark comments,

```
result(1:COUNT(val)) = PACK([(i,i=1,SIZE(val))], val)
```

avoids tracking this size separately.

Finally, with `result` an allocatable (Fortran 2003) array you needn't even (but still can) worry about counting the number of wanted indices and that the array is sufficiently large:

```
result = PACK([(i,i=1,SIZE(val))], val)
```